# Getting items with alamofire and passing it to a tableview in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a swift project where I user Alamofire and swiftyJson to make API calls and I return a bunch of JSON values. I have a category and a product Model classes which is passed to a TableViewController and everything displays well. I store the selected categories ID and SLUG in a variable. The problem I am facing now is how to pass the products associated with the selected category to the productsTableViewController. The selected category JSON looks like this

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/13/",
        "id": 13,
        "title": "ada",
        "description": "how all this",
        "structure": "standalone",
        "date_created": "2018-05-13T17:41:59.935158Z",
        "date_updated": "2018-05-26T17:25:19.024144Z",
        "recommended_products": [],
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Gender",
                "value": "Male"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            "Clothes"
        ],
        "images": [

            {
                "id": 11,
                "original": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/products/2018/05/f4.jpg",
                "caption": "",
                "display_order": 3,
                "date_created": "2018-05-26T17:25:19.155159Z",
                "product": 13
            }
        ],

    },
```

I have my selected category as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let category = CategoryServices.instance.categories[indexPath.row]
        CategoryServices.instance.selectedCategory = category

        print(category)

        let index = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
        tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIFY_CATEGORY_SELECTED, object: nil)

        //pull revel back on selected
        self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
    }
```

I have my default product display i.e all products as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_CELL, for: indexPath) as? ProductsCell {
            let product = ProductServices.instance.products[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(product: product)


            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

The product cell is

```
func configureCell(product: Products) -> Void {

        productPriceLabel.text = product.productPrice
        producNameBtn.setTitle(product.productTitle, for: .normal)
        if (product.productImg.count > 0 ) {
            productImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: product.productImg[0]) )
        } else {
            productImg.image = UIImage(named: "image_not_found")
        }
```

The categorySercices.swift

```
func findProductsForCategory(categorySlug: String, categoryId: Int, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

        Alamofire.request("\(URL_CATEGORY_PRODUCT)\(categorySlug)_\(categoryId)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in

            print("URL_CATEGORY_PRODUCT \(URL_CATEGORY_PRODUCT)")
            if response.result.error == nil {

                guard let data = response.data else {return}

                do {
                    if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {

                        for item in json {

                            let url = item["url"].stringValue
                            let id = item["id"].intValue
                            let title = item["title"].stringValue
                            let imagesList = item["images"].arrayValue
                            let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].stringValue}
                            let currency = item["price"]["currency"].stringValue
                            let price = item["price"]["excl_tax"].stringValue
                            let product = Products(productUrl: url, id: id, productTitle: title, productImg: imagesURL, productPrice: "\(currency) \(price)")
                            self.products.append(product)

                        }
                        completion(true)
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("eroorrrre")
                }
            } else {
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
                completion(false)
            }
        }

    }
```

**ProductServices.swift**

```
    class ProductServices {

    //MARK :- SINGLETONS & VARIABLES
    static let instance = ProductServices()
    var products = [Products]()
    var productDetails = [ProductDetail]()
    var availability = [Availability]()
    var price = [Price]()

    var selectedProduct : Products?
    var selectedCategory : Categories?

    //MARK :- ALL PRODUCTS
    func findAllProducts(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

        Alamofire.request(URL_PRODUCTS, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in

            if response.result.error == nil {

                guard let data = response.data else {return}
                do {

                    if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                        for item in json {
                            let url = item["url"].stringValue
                            let id = item["id"].intValue
                            let title = item["title"].stringValue

                            let imagesList = item["images"].arrayValue

                            let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].stringValue}

                            let currency = item["price"]["currency"].stringValue
                            let price = item["price"]["excl_tax"].stringValue



                            let product = Products(productUrl: url, id: id, productTitle: title, productImg: imagesURL, productPrice: "\(currency) \(price)")
                            self.products.append(product)


                        }
                        completion(true)

                        for i in [self.products[0].productImg] {
                        }
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("error")

                }
            } else {
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    //MARK :- PRODUCT DETAILS
    func findIndividualProducts(id: Int, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {


        Alamofire.request("\(URL_PRODUCT_DETAIL)\(id)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in

            if response.result.error == nil {

                do {
                    if let data = response.result.value {

                        let item = JSON(data)


                            let url = item["url"].stringValue
                            let id = item["id"].intValue
                            let title = item["title"].stringValue
                            let description = item["description"].stringValue
                            let recommendedProducts = item["recommended_products"].stringValue
                            let attributes = item["attributes"].arrayValue
                            let categories = item["categories"].arrayValue
                            let productClass = item["product_class"].stringValue

                        let imagesList = item["images"].arrayValue

                        let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].stringValue}
                            let options = item["options"].stringValue
                            let children = item["children"].stringValue


                            let productDetail = ProductDetail(productUrl: url, id: id, productTitle: title, productDescription: description, recommendedProducts: recommendedProducts, attributes: attributes, categories: categories, productClass: productClass, productImg: imagesURL, options: options, children: children)

                            self.productDetails.append(productDetail)

                        completion(true)

                    }

                } catch {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductCell.swift**

```
class ProductsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productStatusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPriceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var producNameBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var productSectionLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


    func configureCell(product: Products) -> Void {

        productPriceLabel.text = product.productPrice
        producNameBtn.setTitle(product.productTitle, for: .normal)

        if (product.productImg.count > 0 ) {
            productImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: product.productImg[0]) )
        } else {
            productImg.image = UIImage(named: "image_not_found")
        }


    }
```

more codes would be supplied on requestswi

Comment: If I understand this correctly your question boils down to how to get your products from the object `findProductsForCategory` is defined in to your `productsTableViewController` (which is probably the object I would have expected the method to be defined in). Please provide some more context on the objects and not just the metods. Btw: If this is how you should parse JSON using `swiftyJSON` I would have to consider it clumsy compared to the `Codable` protocol. You should have a look at it.

Comment: I know how codable works but there are lots of parameters in the JSON and I only want to get the specified ones

Comment: Well, that is a use case `Codable` is perfect for. It just ignores keys that are not defined as keys. As far as I can tell you do not do any transformation `Codable` cannot do automatically, so no custom initialiser necessary. I am pretty sure it would simplify your JSON-handling. But in any case, you should provide us with the class context of the methods you posted (if you are still interested in someone helping you with the main problem that is).

Comment: @Patru I have updated the question ask for codes required. Thanks

Comment: Aehmm, does that mean that _none_ of the objects you present us are defined in your `TableViewController` and you expect us to fix it? Probably not, but your code seems to make clear, that your `ProductServices` are not connected to your `TableViewController`. In this structure you probably have no other choice than to ask for the `products` property. The usual way would be to pass them to the `CompletionHandler` as a parameter, but in order to do that (for you) we would have to see the call to `findAllProducts` (including the enclosing `class`) as it currently stands.

Comment: @Patru I have provided more details as requested

Comment: I am afraid you have _not_. We still do not have an idea which object your `productsTableViewController` actually represents (which seems to be the object you want to fix i _guess_). Instead we get `findProductsForCategory` and `findAllProducts` which do almost the same thing apparently (which they should not), but we do not know where these `find...` methods are called (which I _guess_ should be your `Controller`). Lacking the `CompletionHandler` from the call we cannot tell what they _do_ and why that goes _wrong_.

Comment: The problem is a tough one. There is probably too much code already, but the things needed to understand why you have problems getting your data across to your `productsTableViewController` are still missing. The design of your `CompletionHandler` looks wrong, but it is impossible to tell without seeing these methods being called.